# Reopen-reclose request

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, closed-questions

Long ago, I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1643009/proving-a-compact-lie-group-admits-a-biinvariant-metric). It was never a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72333/compact-lie-group-bi-invariant-metric), since the question was pretty different, and when the question changed it still had a different viewpoint, yet it was closed as duplicate, and currently has only 2 reopen votes, including mine. I then asked an "exact duplicate", [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658705/proving-left-invariance-and-proof-verification-for-right-invariance-for-metric/1664491#1664491), to which Daniel answered in comments, and I just self-answered taking his comment and converting it to an answer. This question is to ask to reopen the first question to reclose it as the question it *really* is a duplicate of, i.e. the third one. And I ask because currently, if someone lands on the first question, he is redirected to a different question, which doesn't actually answer the first question, and so this person might not find an answer, well unless he reads the comments where I should have placed a link to question 3. If we reopen and reclose as a duplicate of question 3, the same person will find the answer. So can we do this?

Comment: I'd just do this via a moderator flag with a less longwinded explication. "This (link)  more recent questions is a much better dupe target than the current. Could you please change it?"

Comment: @quid Whoops, didn't think of that. I only just started using flags and have them sort of associated with review items, since I only ever used them on posts I reviewed (or in one case on a question I reviewed a suggested edit to). Will keep that in mind.

Comment: No problem. Another option would be to post in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office or http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/c-r-u-d-e (in this case I'd go for the former).

Comment: Did I get the reopening/reclosing right? If so, please remove the non-mathematical content from all these posts. They serve no useful role whatsoever.

Comment: @Jyrki yep, you got it right.